# Trigger/Launch Android App with a hyperlink

Tags: android

I am looking a work around to trigger my Android App with a website hyperlink (from Google Chrome) along with some params as well.

Comment: That is generally called "deep link", you should read this article: https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an `<intent-filter>` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="scheme" android:host="host.com" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

Link to it in html code like this:

```
<a href="scheme://host.com/parameter1/parameter2">
```

When the link is clicked, your app will be launched. You can get the params in you app like this:

```
// From link: scheme://host.com/foo/bar
Uri myData = getIntent().getData();
String scheme = data.getScheme(); // "scheme"
String host = data.getHost(); // "host.com"
List<String> parameters = data.getPathSegments();
String parameter1 = params.get(0); // "foo"
String parameter2 = params.get(1); // "bar"
```

Note that you can use `http` as your scheme to handle ordinary links to a particular host.

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958701/launch-custom-android-application-from-android-browser) for additional info, and look at the docs page on [intent-filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html).

Hope this helps!